# How to sum up counts in file one and write in interval in file two in python or R?

Tags: python, r

I am very new to Python, but I can't find answers to my specific amateur question...

I have two files, file 1 contains numbers and counts:

20 1
23 5
22 90
99 4
43 10
50 63
60  9

etc.

file 2 contains intervals:

0 19
20 39
40 59
60 79
80 99

I plan to read file 2 one line at a time, then count up the sums from file 1 that belongs the interval in file 2. so the output will be like this:

0 19 0
20 39 96
40 59 73
60 79 9
80 99 4

I am struggling to write a loop for it. I can do this in R, but the entire file is too large and it take ages to complete. any pointers will be appreciated!

Thank you very much.

Comment: Step 1.  Write some code.  Step 2.  Share the code here.  Step 3.  Ask **specific** questions about the code you posted.

Comment: It would be good to know.. how many lines are in the file, what is the maximum size of an interval, what is the minimum and maximum number in the file.

Answer (score 3):

```
# Assuming files are open, for brevity

counts = {}
for line in file_1.readlines():
    number, count = line.split()
    counts[int(number)] = int(count)

results = []
for line in file_2.readlines():
    min, max = line.split()
    min, max = int(min), int(max)

    max += 1 # If your ranges are inclusive

    count = sum([counts.get(number,0) for number in range(min, max)])
    results += line + str(count)

 output_file.write('\n'.join(results))
```